# WordPress CLI giving "killed" message

Tags: wordpress

I have a "swift" WordPress hosting package with a2hosting.

I had been using the command line "wp media import *.JPG". This was working great but now I just get back a message "killed". Any idea why this would be and how to resolve please?

Comment: A quick search on Google found me this: [WP-CLI Process Killed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/333752/wp-cli-process-killed). Sounds like you may need to reach out to your hosting for help with this issue.

Comment: That’s look great thanks, I will try it in the morning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the problem was due to import of one particular image. Maybe because it's file size (21mb) was over some kind of memory threshold.